# Objective-C Framework PSMTabBarControl does not work - NSTabView Tabs with Style

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks, nstabview, psmtabbarcontrol

In my App I'm trying to get [PSMTabBarControl](http://www.positivespinmedia.com/dev/PSMTabBarControl.html) working, but all I do - nothing...

I have copied the framework File in my Frameworks folder of my App, then included it. In my InterfaceBuilder (3.2.1) I was able to drag and drop the PSMTabBarControl to my Window and link it with the NSTabView (PSM -> tabView -> NSTabView && NSTabView -> delegate -> PSM), but after i tried a Demo (apple+r) I cant see the Tabs...

Tried all I can - but dont know why..

Am I doing sth. wrong?

Which other Framework or Source I can use to create Tabs like Firefox oder Safari?

Thank you!

Comment: Interface Builder 1.3.2? Are you trying to make this work on NeXTStep?

Comment: hah :D nice - sorry my error - i mean 3.2.1

Answer (score 3):

I've ported a version of it and updated it all to work with IB 3.0+.

http://codaset.com/robertjpayne/psmtabbarcontrol/

It doesn't have much documentation but if you have decent Cocoa knowledge you should be able to work it out.

-Robert

Comment: Hey Robert! The ibplugin was broken, but I fixed it. You can pull my changes from here: `git://github.com/splicer/psmtabbarcontrol.git`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will not work in the Demo mode, you need to build your app.

Comment: Unfortunately the current version of palette is not working in the recent IB so I can't test it on my own. I recommend to check Adium source because the use this UI object.

Comment: im using the latest IB to - you cant add the palette but in the tab "Class" you can find PSMTabBarControl or you can drop in a view and change its class to PSMTabBarControl. Its the same